# Redmine git Can't locate object method "some_auth_required"

Tags: git, perl, redmine, freebsd

I am trying to configure git auth thought reedmine on Freebsd. When i clone my repo i see error at httpd_error.log

```
Can't locate object method "some_auth_required" via package "Apache2::Redmine" at /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16/mach/Apache2/Redmine.pm line 322.\n
```

I cant understand if i need to install something or anything else?
Thx for help

Comment: I can't find Apache2::Redmine. I can find Net::Redmine. I wonder where Apache2::Redmine came from. Maybe it came with Redmine.

Comment: Yeap, i have copied it from redmine/extra/svn

Answer (score 0):

I suggest grepping the rest of the Redmine code for `some_auth_required`.

You'll locate any other places that it's called (aside from `/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.16/mach/Apache2/Redmine.pm line 322`) and you'll see if it's defined anywhere.

If defined, then figure out why the file that defines it isn't `use`d by Apache2/Redmine.pm

Comment: Apache2>grep 'sub add' *  
    PerlSections.pm:sub add_config { 
    ServerUtil.pm:  sub add_my_version {
    SizeLimit.pm:sub add_cleanup_handler {

But i install all required apache perl lib

Comment: Why did you grep for 'sub add' when the missing subroutine is called 'some_auth_required'?

Comment: Even some_
grep 'some_' * -R
Access.pm:  $need_auth = $r->some_auth_required();
Access.pm:=head2 C<some_auth_required>
Access.pm:  $need_auth = $r->some_auth_required();
RequestRec.pm:  $r->status($some_code);

And i have use Apache2::Access qw(); in redmine.pm

Comment: but try "grep -R 'sub some_auth_required' "   to find where that method is defined.  if you don't find the definition, then it is potentially a bug, and I would contact the manufacturer about it.